# Can't translate 2D with Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

A while ago I was successfully processing DWG files with the Design Automation API, but now these same jobs fail and I can't figure out why. It only successfully processes files that contain 3D entities. The ones with only 2d (like planes, etc) now fail. I think it has to do with an Autocad command from the forge server called : **_publishtof2d** , which used to work and now stops the process and returns an error.

I will include logs of the same file but with different status:

Success (04/21/2022):

```
[04/21/2022 19:52:54] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[HostDwg].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[Publish2View22].path)\" /s $(settings[script].path)"
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": "(command \"_MODEL\")\n(command \"_VSCURRENT\" \"2\")\n(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtof2d\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
  },
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b"
"ActivityId":"file.bc_svf_publish_2+v_1"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.AutoCAD_22!22"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"AutoCAD.Publish2View22!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "HostDwg": {
    "localName": "$(HostDwg)",
    "url": "https://..../Masked:ePAYyStW4+jWo1uwqtj08cnywV0=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    }
  },
  "Result": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "result",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:4wW9TLRS3OWJfjgtoNstokBvwac=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:4N8X7SfrU2rOnm0rnReEZ6tl0Ug=",
      "Content-type": "application/zip"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "https://..../Masked:78IQIYFNYw9S1xhb8bjTvwCP7n8=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "https://..../Masked:SOvffNSgrNCsg/8OjSUxfLhEqKo=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    },
    "verb": "post"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 400,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[04/21/2022 19:52:54] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\result" has been created.
[04/21/2022 19:52:54] Starting work item 0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b
[04/21/2022 19:52:54] Start download phase.
[04/21/2022 19:52:54] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://..../forge/viewer/documents/00000000/0000/156/156_model.dwg'
[04/21/2022 19:52:55] '1116178' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\156_model.dwg.
[04/21/2022 19:52:55] End downloading file from 'https://..../forge/viewer/documents/00000000/0000/156/156_model.dwg'.
[04/21/2022 19:52:55] End download phase successfully.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\156_model.dwg" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package" /s T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\setting_script.scr]
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Start script phase.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\tmp\accc58522).
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2017 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (O.47.Z.27)
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Execution Path:
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\userdata.
[04/21/2022 19:52:56] Version Number: O.47.Z.27 (UNICODE)
[04/21/2022 19:52:57] Loading Modeler DLLs.
[04/21/2022 19:52:57] Substituting [simplex.shx] for [MONOTXT4.shx].
[04/21/2022 19:52:57] Substituting [simplex.shx] for [Swis721 BlkEx BT].
[04/21/2022 19:52:57] Regenerating model.
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command:
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: Enter BACKSPACE to interrupt script.
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command:
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: (command "_MODEL")
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] _MODEL
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: (command "_VSCURRENT" "2")
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] _VSCURRENT
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Enter an option [2dwireframe/Wireframe/Hidden/Realistic/Conceptual/Shaded/shaded with Edges/shades of Gray/SKetchy/X-ray/Other] <2dwireframe>: 2
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: (command "_prepareforpropertyextraction" "index.json")
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] _prepareforpropertyextraction
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] CoInitialize(APARTMENT) Succeeded: HRESULT=0x1 CODE=0x1 FACILITY=0x0 SEVERITY=0x0. Continuing.
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Enter name of JSON index file [c:\data\index.json]: index.json
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Command: (command "_indexextractor" "index.json")
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] _indexextractor Enter name of JSON index file [c:\data\index.json]: index.json
[04/21/2022 19:53:01] Indexing T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\156_model.dwg to index.json
[04/21/2022 19:53:02] dwgextractor: dwgindxcoremgd-indexextractorcommand-runextractor: ExtractIndex: elapsedSeconds=0.8241431
[04/21/2022 19:53:02] Indexing completed successfully.
[04/21/2022 19:53:02] *** Run EXTRACTOREND to generate the bubble.json file. ***
[04/21/2022 19:53:02] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:02] Command: (command "_publishtof2d" "./output/result.svf")
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] _publishtof2d
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Specify folder path for F2D results: ./output/result.svf _.plan
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Enter an option [Current ucs/Ucs/World] <Current>: _world Regenerating model.
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] _.perspective
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Enter new value for PERSPECTIVE <0>: 0
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] PUBLISHLAYOUTTHUMBNAILS: 32.000 milliseconds Name="Model"
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\156_model-Model_100.png
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\156_model-Model_200.png
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\156_model-Model_400.png
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Wrote thumbnail results: .\output\156_model-Model.thumbnails.json
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] _.regen Regenerating model.
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] PUBLISHLAYOUT: Name="Model"
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Effective plotting area:  208.41 wide by 250.60 high
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Effective plotting area:  208.41 wide by 250.60 high
[04/21/2022 19:53:03] Plotting viewport 2.
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] PUBLISHLAYOUTTIMER: 1641.000 milliseconds
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] !ACESAPI:acesRunExe(T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe,"T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\156_model-Model.dwfx")
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] !!!!This is an API callback => "!ACESAPI:acesRunExe(T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe,"T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\156_model-Model.dwfx")"
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] Start processing API request acesRunExe.
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] Arguments => name="T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe", args=""T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\output\156_model-Model.dwfx""
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] Start child process for "T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe".
[04/21/2022 19:53:05] Start application dwf2f2d.exe standard output dump.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] WARNING : Cannot access index.json file.
Objects ids size according to Windows API: 2657
Buffer size is : 8891
Total decompressed bytes : 8890
Input file size is : 2657
ERROR : dwf2f2d: Unhandled vectored exception processing file
execptionCode : 0x4001000a
ERROR : dwf2f2d: Unhandled vectored exception processing file
execptionCode : 0x40010006
WARNING : loadSheet, index==m_currentPage==0
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] End application dwf2f2d.exe standard output dump.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Error: AutoCAD Core Console output contains error(s).
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] End child process.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Current API request with result: 0
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Done processing API request with result: success, Length: 1, Time spent: 4.5358801 seconds.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Mark encountered
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Command: (command "_createbubblepackage" "./output" "./result" "" "")
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] _createbubblepackage
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Enter folder path from which to create bubble [T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b]: ./output
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Enter folder path to store bubble output [.\Result]: ./result
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Specify the pathname for the drawing file [T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\156_model.dwg]:
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Please specify full path for additional file to be included:
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Generate bubble.json in: ./output
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-buildmetadata: dwfThumbMap: size=1
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-buildmetadata: dwfToF2dMap: size=1 outputPath=.\output\
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-buildmetadata: dwfToF2dMap.copyMetadataContents: (success) path=156_model-Model.dwfx
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-buildmetadata: dwfToF2dMap: additional-files: 6
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-buildmetadata: created: filename=".\output\bubble.json" bubbleguid="" propdbguid=""
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] dwgextractor: dwgindxmgd-utils-cleanupdwftof2dmetadatafiles: filename=.\output\2dab762a-ab74-066d-3624-0578a138641d_f2d\bubble.json renamed.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] A total of 24 files are copied to result folder.
[04/21/2022 19:53:10] Command: nil
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Total time spent on aces call back API is 4.5358801 seconds.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] End script phase.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Start upload phase.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Zipping directory T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\result as T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\result.zip.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b\result.zip': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bc_svf/objects/156.zip'
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] End upload phase successfully.
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Job finished with result Succeeded
[04/21/2022 19:53:11] Job Status:
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": ".../0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=4080&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHwaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDGyndIv1x8qFc%2FmutWj6PmPQ7VjCvYZhyhP8%2Fxh5w9QQIgUBq1CrALHgrvLF1p39x6E5bs9pSkMS%2FMd%2BMDiWtCXjcqmwIINBADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDGW%2Fi6NXyGbqaNd37yr4AX4SDhhk%2BjamSCiR0vNwMqt%2Fw3kMltYxPGW6CAFNyqpahs0YqjvS1JdLqloB1JMgXp8ibd%2FSPGnpk5AJaXCp%2BFwno6o40NHpIF%2ByB6J0rxeBnjQHQOJDYJVI%2FYDNk1qwBV%2FfxH49fTOumu9OuVm14xFaX7xIZy13g2HGSYXx%2Bt3bRsrXRCIA0yNugLdg7LxsCxusbcitaTB0tXMz2SxbF%2BnpW0%2Bvz2ivqtJsOreD05q%2F48ROelvTmzrp2GiFdkr4Yz9rWb22vxKqyPqGY5OESiUDgxZMMDW44JUC9aN7XRak0eaXFjcDL%2FjYtSZwUOT5mHUX710RsXDSMNvYhpMGOpoBXL8h%2FO94M%2BDM4UnSDQJ%2BuJfu%2BpfVaj9zTONMrCTb5oQpFM24HW47vptNrVRgpQuertTdBimajFGqsgbV5KLJ96ShJCO4I9Lz%2BSz2WF4Da7QLthX0WHUnm2I7mOHUeUxUxDpRHuUutpBgECzUoL%2FtONPgl9l3XEakLpLT58mKLLbWQXdUg5wmOfY%2FIK%2Bi0%2FKJ0SrblmFpqqc5rg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3BGBONU54/20220421/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220421T195254Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=23bee4b614ec6d84a6423af43b8c1cca03f1e702be8aeb0ceb276be1e6c958fa",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-04-21T19:52:54.7370052Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-04-21T19:52:54.8901849Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-04-21T19:52:56.4028888Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-04-21T19:53:11.5336378Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-04-21T19:53:11.8331367Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1116178,
    "bytesUploaded": 507617
  },
  "id": "0ef7d3d4c92344899e5a4877b7e41c8b"
}
```

Failed (10/05/2022):

```
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[HostDwg].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[Publish2View22].path)\" /s $(settings[script].path)"
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": "(command \"_MODEL\")\n(command \"_VSCURRENT\" \"2\")\n(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtof2d\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
  },
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e"
"ActivityId":"file.bc_svf_publish_2+v_1"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.AutoCAD_22!22"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"AutoCAD.Publish2View22!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "HostDwg": {
    "localName": "$(HostDwg)",
    "url": "https://..../Masked:MuGJFxvDKwZo/9uLo8w039uW+Dg=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    }
  },
  "Result": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "result",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:Li0H3pLhRD251Jv3hyKv8BSfRV0=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:6KXFLHeAMLPLdUCscKxy9vGk8xM=",
      "Content-type": "application/zip"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "https://..../Masked:1cQkp/wyr5YxYGwkCOxvQrAeOSY=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "https://..../Masked:nhVMYa2x3JHxwlm1bxUGtvo/0PM=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:kLy2SjSKmGEn6G6ePswwWWDxSaQ="
    },
    "verb": "post"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\result" has been created.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Starting work item 82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Start download phase.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://..../forge/viewer/documents/00000000/0000/188/188_model.dwg'
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] End downloading file. Source=https://..../forge/viewer/documents/00000000/0000/188/188_model.dwg,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\188_model.dwg,BytesDownloaded=1116146,Duration=120ms
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] End download phase successfully.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\188_model.dwg" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package" /s T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\setting_script.scr]
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Start script phase.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\tmp\accc12322).
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2017 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (O.47.Z.27)
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Execution Path:
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[05/10/2022 20:06:58] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\userdata.
[05/10/2022 20:06:59] Version Number: O.47.Z.27 (UNICODE)
[05/10/2022 20:06:59] Loading Modeler DLLs.
[05/10/2022 20:07:00] Substituting [simplex.shx] for [MONOTXT4.shx].
[05/10/2022 20:07:00] Substituting [simplex.shx] for [Swis721 BlkEx BT].
[05/10/2022 20:07:00] Regenerating model.
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command:
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: Enter BACKSPACE to interrupt script.
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command:
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: (command "_MODEL")
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] _MODEL
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: nil
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: (command "_VSCURRENT" "2")
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] _VSCURRENT
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Enter an option [2dwireframe/Wireframe/Hidden/Realistic/Conceptual/Shaded/shaded with Edges/shades of Gray/SKetchy/X-ray/Other] <2dwireframe>: 2
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: nil
[05/10/2022 20:07:01] Command: (command "_prepareforpropertyextraction" "index.json")
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] _prepareforpropertyextraction
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] CoInitialize(APARTMENT) Succeeded: HRESULT=0x1 CODE=0x1 FACILITY=0x0 SEVERITY=0x0. Continuing.
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] Enter name of JSON index file [c:\data\index.json]: index.json
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] Command: nil
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] Command: (command "_indexextractor" "index.json")
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] _indexextractor Enter name of JSON index file [c:\data\index.json]: index.json
[05/10/2022 20:07:02] Indexing T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\188_model.dwg to index.json
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] dwgextractor: dwgindxcoremgd-indexextractorcommand-runextractor: ExtractIndex: elapsedSeconds=0.7220319
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Indexing completed successfully.
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] *** Run EXTRACTOREND to generate the bubble.json file. ***
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Command: nil
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Command: (command "_publishtof2d" "./output/result.svf")
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] _publishtof2d
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Specify folder path for F2D results: ./output/result.svf _.plan
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Enter an option [Current ucs/Ucs/World] <Current>: _world Regenerating model.
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] _.perspective
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Enter new value for PERSPECTIVE <0>: 0
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] PUBLISHLAYOUTTHUMBNAILS: 31.000 milliseconds Name="Model"
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\188_model-Model_100.png
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\188_model-Model_200.png
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Wrote layout-thumbnail: .\output\188_model-Model_400.png
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Wrote thumbnail results: .\output\188_model-Model.thumbnails.json
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] _.regen Regenerating model.
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] PUBLISHLAYOUT: Name="Model"
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Effective plotting area:  208.41 wide by 250.60 high
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Effective plotting area:  208.41 wide by 250.60 high
[05/10/2022 20:07:03] Plotting viewport 2.
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] PUBLISHLAYOUTTIMER: 1547.000 milliseconds
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] !ACESAPI:acesRunExe(T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe,"T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\188_model-Model.dwfx")
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] !!!!This is an API callback => "!ACESAPI:acesRunExe(T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe,"T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\188_model-Model.dwfx")"
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] Start processing API request acesRunExe.
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] Arguments => name="T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe", args=""T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\index.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e\output\188_model-Model.dwfx""
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] Start child process for "T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package\Publish2View22.bundle\Contents\dwf2f2d\dwf2f2d.exe".
[05/10/2022 20:07:05] Start application dwf2f2d.exe standard output dump.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] WARNING : Cannot access index.json file.
Objects ids size according to Windows API: 2657
Buffer size is : 8891
Total decompressed bytes : 8890
Input file size is : 2657
ERROR : dwf2f2d: Unhandled vectored exception processing file
execptionCode : 0x4001000a
ERROR : dwf2f2d: Unhandled vectored exception processing file
execptionCode : 0x40010006
WARNING : loadSheet, index==m_currentPage==0
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] End application dwf2f2d.exe standard output dump.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Error: AutoCAD Core Console output contains error(s).
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] End child process.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Current API request with result: 0
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Done processing API request with result: success, Length: 1, Time spent: 3.3998533 seconds.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Error: Application accoreconsole.exe exits with code -1 which indicates an error.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Total time spent on aces call back API is 3.3998533 seconds.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] End script phase.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[05/10/2022 20:07:09] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": ".../82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=4080&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEQaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDzMyBncYp3LRT3sUj25NiuFn%2FSB3XQDR0vbjI7c6usFgIhAOzm8Lf%2Bgbww4q9KO85RZV9l2KToaJomkeUIJKlu4V%2BBKpsCCBwQAxoMMjIwNDczMTUyMzEwIgzwV1qJzL2OQsjidHEq%2BAEVRt5JXrQszF3SnmTTaiWdb%2BcbM0H8chsEdyfQtd5%2FWoN0BFKlxKVqI4CzNXaaOieGi4DnTJ7o0rBRau0DgfM1nVh08jkyFVDyOiz1l%2BEd%2FW0EoBCVaDV6klVXZHptv5hdQhXZ1W8IKtq1Ys%2FAal0rAkherr3cffHINcVNJRbG3Hi92dOoDYyniklmHdGVN4bRbGdC48ASCcJW%2FCvyD8%2F2coMS%2FFPg2dwVxGJj3SKxm7VllYLkklvnXHwgO2RPcJW9p2CHxFrGIAjp6hR6vLvlNeaRCWnqiXYpvdOjq5CJeUJX2QLFKS4cOEMeGECcuALitvJII76PjjDj9OqTBjqZAW6yz75X1%2Fgtp2aOoTUWwtIQr4pF1%2F%2B5i%2BRNBVvqMyBbpdNp%2BK%2FOEJezf38mwn9neENF519wOUJQ8RIJDs%2BQ1w3dL6QHbccI7ByBtpuRClyfAKav3kw%2FekRGzdameTxXz1IJ3oxqn1l9WkrnxqtCNdxAm9NeK8I7h5uFRTTuk7XtmmNIyoPwdMnAGCseatQ6dvLh1iuZJWwpTw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3BPQFSQGF/20220510/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220510T200658Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=37281ffb0e0fb4876e64da822967648725eba899e2cb7f860ce126e0fc69ad19",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-05-10T20:06:58.0664964Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-05-10T20:06:58.1873709Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-05-10T20:06:58.4198479Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-05-10T20:07:09.1172498Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1116146
  },
  "id": "82a793458a8d49a78a6cc10b92bb645e"
}
```

I've even tried a very simple DWG, a rectangle, but Design Automation gives me the same error.
I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi tomillo,

We are looking into this. We'll get back to you as soon as we know more.

albert

Comment: We've identified the issue. It was introduced on 5/3/2022. We are working on a fix. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: What was the bug?  I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The fix was deployed to production at 15:00PST on 5/23/2022.
I apologize for the disruption.

Comment: Thanks Albert, it's working fine. What was causing this error? Thank you very much for helping us.

Comment: This was a regression caused by some completely unrelated change. We'll improve our test coverage to avoid this in the future.